# why i can't see the Tab of the tabHost?

Tags: android

I did the same code as on the googles example - and i want to see the tab that i can click on them and switch between the tabs.

I can't see the tabs ..

The code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Action"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/black">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="This is tab 1" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Memo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="This is tab 2" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Settings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="This is tab 3" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Would you provide the Activity?

Comment: without this Activity its also does not work

Comment: Tablayout is better

Comment: You can check my answer.@Yanshof

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Add the `TabHost` id in your xml code

   ```
   android:id="@+id/tabhost"
   ```
2. add `TabHost` initialization information in `onCreate()` method

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host);

       TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
       mTabHost.setup();
       mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Action").setIndicator("title1", null).setContent(R.id.Action));
       mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Memo").setIndicator("title2", null).setContent(R.id.Memo));
      mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Settings").setIndicator("title3", null).setContent(R.id.Settings));
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Yanshof ! Could you check my answer?Thank you.